# First two moments of a quadratic form in which the vector and matrix are random (though independent)

Tags: probability, variance, moments, quadratic-form

$\DeclareMathOperator\tr{\mathrm{tr}}$Let $x$ be a standard normal $p$-variate random variable, which is independent of a symmetric positive definite random matrix $Y$. I would like to compute the mean and variance of the quadratic form $x^TYx$.

If $Y$ were not a random variable, then we could argue that the fact that quadratic forms are diagonalizable means that without the loss of generality we can assume that $Y$ is a diagonal matrix. And an entry-by-entry computation shows that the mean will be $\tr(Y)$ with variance $2 \tr(Y)$.

But if $Y$ is a random variable, I'm not sure it's so easy since though the mean is still $\tr(\mathbb{E}[Y])$, the variance of each entry now depends on $Y$ in a more complicated way, and since diagonalizing changes the diagonal entries in non-trivial ways, is it no longer possible to relate the variance to the trace of $Y$ or a related expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\E{\mathbb E}
\DeclareMathOperator\tr{\mathrm{tr}}
\DeclareMathOperator\Cov{\mathrm{Cov}}
\DeclareMathOperator\Var{\mathrm{Var}}$
Using trace rotation and the commutivity of linear operators:
\begin{align}
\E[x^T Y x]
&= \E[\tr(x^T Y x)]
\\&= \E[\tr(Y x x^T)]
\\&= \tr(\E[Y x x^T])
\\&= \tr(\E[Y] \E[x x^T])
\\&= \tr(\E[Y])
.\end{align}

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_%28statistics%29#Variance) or [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1304228/19147) tell us, slightly disagreeing with what you said, that for normal $x$ and symmetric $Y$
$$\Var[x^T Y x \mid Y] = 2 \tr(Y Y).$$
Then via the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), for random $Y$ we have
\begin{align}
\Var(x^T Y x)
&= \E_Y \Var_x(x^T Y x \mid Y) + \Var_Y( \E_x[x^T Y x \mid Y] )
\\&= \E[ 2 \tr( Y^2 ) ] + \Var( \tr(Y \E[x x^T]))
\\&= 2 \tr(\E[ Y^2 ]) + \Var(\tr(Y))
.\end{align}